# Android onLocationChanged with Direction using Google Map Api v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am making a tourist map for android with Google Map Markers and Polylines and I succeeded in doing that but now i need to add something that can make my app more friendly user. so I wanted to put this feature to my app.

Something like that.

[image]

with live update when the user move.

Anyhow this my app

[image]

I don't know how to start on that placing DIRECTION. anyone can help me?

Tried using this method but i failed.

`
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

```
    // Getting longitude of the current location
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));



    start = latLng;

    Log.d("Location Changed: ", latLng.toString());
    //etLog.append("Location Changed: " + latLng.toString() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

`

Comment: Could you show your code for onLocationChanged??You have considered using LocationManager

Comment: @BhanuChowdary question edited

Comment: So when you debug do the onLocationChanged method getting executed??

Comment: To get confirmed .... Are you trying it from emulator?If you are trying from emulator in the emulator control you need to change lat and long in order to execute this function.And are you checking if gps is on ??

Comment: @BhanuChowdary i used mobile zenfone,  Location was enabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98062/discussion-between-mardagz-and-bhanu-chowdary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code you will get updated location live on map.

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener{ 
final String TAG = "mapactivity";
LocationRequest  locationRequest;
GoogleAPiClient googleApiClient;
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}
@Override
public void onStop(){
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i){
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");

}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult){
    Log.i(TAG, "connection failed");

}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle){
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
    Double curLat = location.getLatitude();//current latitude
    Double curLong = location.getLongitude();//current longitude
} }
```

Comment: what does it mean?

Error
` java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sprikiwiki.tourist.touristmap.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener`


onConnected method

`LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);`

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: of course  how can i get the google map without that permission.. hmm

Comment: In your code do not cast this line((com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this). check my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98069/discussion-between-mardagz-and-prathap-badavath).

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable google map directions api from google developer console. To get directions you have to pass two latlngs as source and destination with your api key you will get all the points between given source and destination draw the polyline between them you will get directions polyline drawn between source and destination as shown in screenshot follow [this link.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints)

Comment: How is this related to the question??