# Getting error after creating object : 'LocationServices() has private acces in 'com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices'

Tags: android, android-location

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /*
     * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to
     * handle callbacks.
     */
    LocationServices    mLocationServices = new LocationServices(this, this, this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

I was following the training on android developer site, the `LocationClient()` is depreciated so i used `LocationServices()`.
Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: Declare LocationServices mLocationServices outside onCreate().

Comment: check [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304279/android-onlocationchanged-with-direction-using-google-map-api-v2/) link.

Comment: Thanks, it was a compilation issue. but it is ok now.